# How to use mysqli_query inside of a class

Tags: php

I am designing a web page in PHP 5.6.16, trying to use some OOP ideas.
When I include file classnews.php in file index.php, I get the error

```
Undefined variable: connect in classtin.php
```

classdb.php:

```
<?php
class db
{
    public $hostname = "localhost";
    public $user= "root";
    public $pass = "";
    public $db = "test";
    /* public $connect = NULL;
    public $result = NULL;*/

    function __construct()
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->user, $this->pass,$this->db);
        mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8');
    }
}
?>
```

classnews.php:

```
<?php
    include_once('classdb.php');

    class tin extends db
    {
        public function tinmoi()
        {
            $sql= "select * from emp ";
            $result= mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are probably lacking '$this'. Please ready more about OOP here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Thank you for me!.Can you speak clearly?I am newbie.

Comment: Fixed problem description to be readable.  Improved code formatting.  Removed bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to class members by `$this`. Same way you did with `$this->hostname`, for example.

Modifying parts of your code you have:

```
class db
{
    public $hostname = "localhost";
    public $user= "root";
    public $pass = "";
    public $db = "test";

    public $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->user, $this->pass,$this->db);
        mysqli_set_charset($this->connection,'utf8');
    }
}

class tin extends db
{
    public function tinmoi()
    {
        $sql = "select * from emp ";
        return mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    }
}
```

Again, I would strongly suggest going through basics of OOP in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php